How to make shortcuts to batch files in Windows 11 that are set to minimize, actually minimize the window?
In Windows XP, 7, 8, and 8.1, it is trivial to create a shortcut to a batch file, and then set the Run type in the shortcut's properties to Minimize.  This would cause the batch file to run minimized, as expected.
In Windows 11, by default, this no longer works.  Using default settings, Windows 11 seems to ignore that setting in the shortcut to the batch file.
How does one make shortcuts to batch files in Windows 11 that are set to minimize, actually minimize the batch file's window?

I can recommend three different techniques for you:
First Technique
1. In the [Options] tab, enable: Use legacy console (requires relaunch, affects all consoles)
2. In the [Shortcut] tab, under Run: Set it to Minimized.


Second Technique
You have the option to edit the shortcut path to your .bat file and include a command for PowerShell to act on your current window and minimize it:
"D:\path\to\your\target\file.bat" & "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoP -W style "file.bat" ^; exit

Note: In my tests on Windows 11 Pro / Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.4317], it works perfectly. That’s why I’m suggesting this alternative.

Third Technique
Another suggestion would be to edit your batch file and add this command to hide, minimize, or restore the window to normal at the appropriate execution task/time. Below is an example of how to do that:
@echo off

set "_timeout=C:\Windows\System32\timeout.exe"
set "_ps1bin=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"

"%_timeout%" /t 10 /nobreak | =;(
     echo/You can try getting a little help from PowerShell with the -WindowStyle option:
     echo/ -WindowStyle [option] ::  Hidden, Normal, Minimized...
    );=

"%_timeout%" /t 05 /nobreak | "%_ps1bin%" -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden ;exit

"%_timeout%" /t 05 /nobreak | "%_ps1bin%" -NoProfile -WindowStyle Normal ;exit

"%_timeout%" /t 05 /nobreak | "%_ps1bin%" -NoProfile -WindowStyle Minimized ;exit

"%_timeout%" /t 05 /nobreak | "%_ps1bin%" -NoProfile -WindowStyle Normal ;exit


Fantastic answer! Thanks so much.  If I'm reading what you wrote correctly, I think you are proposing 3 different techniques.  I'll make an edit to make that more apparent.  If I'm mistaken, please edit or revert my edit.  Thanks again!

Your edit is welcome, and I must say it's much better than the previous one. I appreciate your time and attention in communicating!

Glad to hear, and you're most welcome.  It's rare to get such an incredibly high quality answer these days.  Not only are all the techniques you provided useful, they are all unique, so I can implement them in different situations.  Thank you again.  I'm now going to research the pros/cons of clicking the checkbox specified in the first technique.

BTW, I'll likely be marking this as the accepted answer in a few days, but I always want to give others a chance to answer too.  I'm human, so if I forget to mark an accepted answer, and you remember, feel free to ping me, and I'll gratefully mark the best answer as accepted.

Your actions are appropriate and in good alignment with the platform's purpose; I’m on the same path..

In the 3rd technique, you have a space between the windows style and the semicolon indicating the end of the command (and before exit).  Is this simply stylistic?  IOW, is there any downside in writing the code as ... -WindowStyle Hidden; exit?

To make it more readable, I did it this way, but it works both ways.

Thanks.  Regarding the 3rd technique: If you know a batch file will always successfully terminate on its own, is it fine to just use ... -WindowStyle Hidden at the beginning of the batch file, and never have a ... -WindowStyle Normal anywhere in the batch file?

My style is like this, though not very readable... d;)

Regarding the 3rd technique: Adding it at the end has no effect if it will close anyway; the change is applied only for the current session and is not permanent once it finishes.

I'll send you a donation so you can buy a few carriage returns and line feeds! ;)

I'll send you a donation: I accept out of courtesy, but I will decline the use due to my choice and preference for symmetric compression. d;)

LOL! Fair enough! I've been experimenting with the 3rd technique, and discovered 2 things: (1) the space after Hidden (etc.) and before the semicolon is required. (2) Hidden doesn't actually hide the window; it only minimizes it. :(

No difference when changing extension.

tyr "^; exit" e see result, plz

No difference adding a caret before the semicolon.

Only these worked for my tests: Minimized ; exit or Minimized ;exit

Same for me.  Are you able to get Hidden ;exit to work to actually hide the window?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
